# How can I analyse and manipulate k-space data of a DICOM imageset?

Tags: fourier-analysis, segmentation

I'm very new to Mathematica. I've some MRI images as 3D DICOM data. I want to get the corresponding k-space data to identify all the signals with their corresponding amplitude, frequency and phase. Based on these, I wish to segment the signals in the frequency domain and after that I wish to convert the segmented data back into time domain.

However, I don't have any idea how to proceed (to be more specific, how to implement this in Mathematica). Can anyone please help me?

**Edit:** I can't delete this post. Please check the following link:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/how-to-analyse-and-manipulate-k-space-data-of-a-dicom-image-dataset

This question was put before I registered in this site. Therefore, I have put the same question on the above link and wish all communications to that link itself.

Comment: If you could add some code showing what you have tried so far, it'll be easier for others to understand where you got stuck. Also adding example data will make it more likely to get some help and potentially increases the applicability of answers for your data set.

Comment: Same question asked twice:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/how-to-analyse-and-manipulate-k-space-data-of-a-dicom-image-dataset.  This one should probably be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an exact duplicate of [(102293)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/how-to-analyse-and-manipulate-k-space-data-of-a-dicom-image-dataset) posted mistakenly under an unregistered account, and should be deleted.

Comment: Maji, please follow the instructions here to merge your accounts http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Lots of people flagged the duplication here. The other post will be auto deleted after a few days because it has no answers and no upvotes.  So I won't bother merging them.